# newman execution throwing TypeError: newman.run is not a function

Tags: postman, newman

I have newman 3.9.3 version installed on my ubuntu box. Want to execute multiple collections from a folder but executing js file through me wired error saying

> TypeError: newman.run is not a function.

Here is my execution script. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var newman = require(process.env.NVM_BIN+'/newman');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('./collections', function (err, files) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    files = files.filter(function (file) {
        return (file.substr(-5) === '.json');
    });

    // now wer iterate on each file name and call newman.run using each file name
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        newman.run({
            environment: require(`${__dirname}/live.postmane_environment.json`),
            collection: require(`${__dirname}/collections/${file}`),
            reporters: ['cli']
        }, function (err) {
            console.info(`${file}: ${err ? err.name : 'ok'}!`);
        });
    });
});
```

Following is the exact error.

/app/postman/execute:15
        newman.run({
               ^

> TypeError: newman.run is not a function
>       at /app/postman/execute:15:16
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at /app/postman/execute:14:11
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

Comment: Does it run if you remove the `process.env.NVM_BIN+` and do a normal require of the module?

Comment: No, even i tried with absolute path of newman utility. It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I've solved this problem by using bash script to run all of my collections available in a folder. that has done the job. but originally i could not understand why "run" is not available for "newman" object.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message and solved installing the nodejs package:

```
npm install --save newman
```

Basically, when you make the bin as reference the nodejs doesnt know how to run:

Instead of:

```
var newman = require(process.env.NVM_BIN+'/newman');
```

Should be:

```
var newman = require('newman');
```